# React native - how to stay on same screen after reload

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have noticed that when I am in clicking reload the navigator opening the home screen.

there is a way to stay on the same screen when the user clicks reload?

this is my navigation code:

AuthNavigation.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'

import WebHome from '../screens/WebHome'
import EditUserHome from '../screens/EditUserHome'
import EditUserInfo from '../screens/EditUserInfo'



const AuthNavigation = createStackNavigator(
  {

    WebHome: { screen: WebHome},
    EditUserHome: { screen: EditUserHome},
    EditUserInfo: { screen: EditUserInfo}
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'WebHome',
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
)

export default AuthNavigation
```

AppNavigation.js:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack'
import Home from '../screens/Home'
const AppNavigation = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Home }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  }
)

export default AppNavigation
```

index.js:

```
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
import Initial from '../screens/Initial'
import AuthNavigation from './AuthNavigation'
import AppNavigation from './AppNavigation'
const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Initial: Initial,
    Auth: AuthNavigation,
    App: AppNavigation
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Initial'
  }
)

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator)

export default AppContainer
```

Answer (score 1):

> when I am in clicking reload the navigator opening the home screen

If you're talking about reloading the app through developer tools - I'm afraid not. The app will reset itself on each reload. As though it were the first time you've opened it.

To get around this while developing you can change the `initialRouteName` value, or force a navigation by using the regular navigate API `navigation.navigate('<route_name>')`.